# Multiple REST interfaces in Play! 2 application

Tags: rest, playframework, playframework-2.0

We have a Play! application where we need to expose a set of REST interfaces to an intranet and a set of REST interfaces we have to expose to the public internet.  They share a data layer so we would like to run them together if possible.  My assumption is that they will be running on different ports.  Being new to Play!, I don't know if this is possible to do within a single Play! instance.  I have looked at modules but that didn't seem to fit what we are doing.  Has anyone had any experience with this sort of scenario?

Forgot to mention we are using Play! 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could restrict/permit access to resources by checking the ip.

```
public class IPLocalSecurity extends Controller {
    @Before
    public static void checkAccess() throws Exception {
        if (!request.remoteAddress.matches("192\.168\.1\.*")) {
             forbidden();
        }
    }
}
```

and use that in the resources controller.

```
@With(IPLocalSecurity.class)
public class IntranetController extends Controller{
    ....
}
```